# MySQL, undo drop database

Tags: mysql

I've accidentally dropped a database inside my server .

I have no backup of it and binary logs are not enabled (shame on me!) ...

Is there any way to restore that db?

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  This is how people learn the hard way to use backups :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be worth looking at this (assuming a recent linux):

https://web.archive.org/web/20110714020437/http://carlo17.home.xs4all.nl/howto/undelete_ext3.html

Original Link (broken):

[http://www.xs4all.nl/~carlo17/howto/undelete_ext3.html](http://www.xs4all.nl/%7Ecarlo17/howto/undelete_ext3.html)

Comment: Unfortunately i'm on OpenVZ, so no ext3 filesystem but a simfs one :(

Comment: 404, link is broken: `Oeps... pagina niet gevonden`

Comment: @Pathros, I re-posted a snapshot of that website

Comment: @gahooa . So you basically undeleted that post! Thank you so much! I'm reading it thoroughly.